# How to exlude all the devices which have low GPU in Android Manifest?

Tags: android, live, wallpaper

Basically, I created a live wallpaper for Android and tried it in my Droid X, Galaxy S, and Fascinate. And I  noticed that it runs smootly in Galaxy S and Fasciante but not in Droid X which has lower GPU. My question is, is there anyway to exlude all the devices which has low GPU in Android Manifest? I am planning to publish this live wallpaper soon. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `supports-screens` to the manifest, and pass in a true false valuefor each size. The below example would exclude all mobile handsets.

Id imagine a solution to narrow everything down to exactly you want would be similar to this.

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="false"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
    <application ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Other things are available as well such as Density values.

See the [Support-Screen Dev Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: What does requiresSmallestWidthDp really do?

Comment: it means the app requires the screen size of at least 600dp wide.

Comment: Oh I see! So when your device has higher dp, it is more capable of playing Live Wallpaper smoothly?

Comment: not sure about that, Id say more GPU power(which usually means bigger screen) would allow it to play it more smoothly. But using that could help you narrow it down. As mentioned in the below post there doesnt seem to be a way to specify GPU power :(.

Comment: So do you think excluding other screens size would reduce the problem at least?

Comment: reduce it yes(IMO quite a bit, maybe post another question using that code? Maybe someone else would know?), solve it completely, prolly not, unless you wanted to target only tablets.

Comment: The set I posted, just as a reference for what you have now, and see if anyone else out there knows a better way to narrow down allowed phones based on GPU

Comment: This is a terrible way to try to do this. You should scale down your app. Do it any other way and you'll be using losing users by your app either sucking on their device, or by flat out denying them from downloading it.

Comment: He was asking how to exclude users though. I was simply answering the OPs question. The OP can do whatever he wants with his app, maybe its a suweeet wallpapaer.

Answer (score 5):

You can exclude specific devices when submitting the app to the market.  Rather do it there than in the manifest, as it's not possible to specify the required GPU in the manifest, and screen size is not necessarily an indicator of GPU power.

Comment: But I am not really sure which one has good or bad GPU devices

Comment: True on size not an indicator of power, but it may be the best he can do, without knowing the GPU power of every device out there.

Comment: Well then you'll have to either research on the internet, or use screen size as a rough indicator of GPU power as in harper89's answer below.  Just a note, his answer currently only allows tablets (xlarge screens), so modify it to your needs.  The Galaxy S falls under largeScreen for instance.

Comment: I keep researching since last weekend and still couldn't find the solution in the internet.  if you have any good sources regarding of this issue, please send me the link. THanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant you'll have to do research on specific device capabilities and exclude the ones that aren't up to it.  Or decide to only include popular devices that you know works with your app.