# How to exclude devices with lower GPU in Android?

Tags: android, live, gpu, wallpaper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to exlude all the devices which have low GPU in Android Manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487183/how-to-exlude-all-the-devices-which-have-low-gpu-in-android-manifest)

Yesterday,  I created a live wallpaper for Android and tried it in my Droid X, Galaxy S, and Fascinate. And I noticed that it runs smootly in Galaxy S and Fasciante but not in Droid X which has lower GPU. So far I can only eliminate a specific devices which has normal-xlarge screen using the code below. But it does not specifically tell whether it has lower GPU. My question is, is there anyway to exlude other devices with lower GPU?

```
<manifest ... >     
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"                       android:normalScreens="false"                       android:largeScreens="false"                       android:xlargeScreens="true"                       
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />     
   </manifest>
```

Comment: why not create some settings that increase/decrease quality? Your app will be most successful if it works for every platform.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for that? And also, my live wallpaper is only 1mb+, and it still fails to play in my Droid X

Comment: it depends on what your live wallpaper is...

Comment: @user858975 it seems there is no way, I was curious about this too but it seems everyones answer is "You are doing it wrong" instead of offering possible solutions(if any do exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not exclude by criteria CPU but you can exclude with criteria API level

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"  />
```

I know this is not well solution but you can go with assumption that if the is on higher sdk level that the program is installed on device that is newer (which usually means faster).
I told you this is not complete solution to your problem but you might find it useful.