# Year 2015- Is there a way to limit download on Android market by cpu/gpu "power" of device?

Tags: android, performance, android-manifest, android-market-filtering

I know this has been asked/answered before but these answers are from 2011. It's not good to necro/duplicate of course but things change over 4 yrs sometimes so I don't "think" I am being unreasonable here. Hopefully, things have changed for this question.

Answered 2011 - [How to exclude devices with lower GPU in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487669/how-to-exclude-devices-with-lower-gpu-in-android)

Answered 2011 - [How to exlude all the devices which have low GPU in Android Manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487183/how-to-exlude-all-the-devices-which-have-low-gpu-in-android-manifest)

I've looked throught the Android manifesto myself a bit to filter out apps search results by various hardware but there was little about processors, or gpu, etc that I could find to help. I searched google for the past couple hours with not much luck. I have never published to Android market so apologies if this is obvious.

I have a game I am planning to release on the Android market but it is graphically intensive and only higer end devices can run it. I have tried running it on an iPad 2 and it barely works so that is my lowest bench mark for Apple store. I have tried running it on a Galaxy 4 tablet 7.0 (Android OS: v4.4.2 (KitKat), Chipset: Marvell PXA1088, CPU: Quad-core 1.2 GHz) and it is unplayable.

I know I will be cutting out a very large potetnial customer base but I need some way to limit the abilty to download if the device is too slow to run the game.

How can this be achieved? Is there a list of basic Android cpu/gpu performace to help filter if the store route can't be done?

Thanks

Comment: If you cut out the majority of devices out there, no-one will use your game. You might be better off making it less resource intensive, so that more people can play it. Afaik, the only filter in Google play is for minimum OpenGL ES version, which may be enough. Otherwise, are you sure _any_ device can play it satisfactorily at all ?

Comment: I am toying with the idea of less resource intensive but only as a last resort. I picked up a Galaxy 4 tab 7 just to start doing Android dev and thought it was a reasonable starting device (it's the most active hardware according to Unity). Is the Galaxy 4 tab 7.0 known to suck for intensive game? It just blows my mind that my 4 yrs old iPad2 performs better than this newer Android device.

Comment: No, that device is not bad, it's probably more of a problem that your game is inefficient. Are you using any game engine, such as Unity ?

Comment: Yes I am using Unity. The game runs at 30fps on iPad2 and 60fps on iPhone 5s. I don't have access to any other android device to see how it performs, unfortunately. I've read through (and implimented I believe) many optimization techniques for Unity and deployment to mobile. It all seemed fine on the Apple side then total bomb on Android side.

Comment: I've never used Unity, but you should be able to debug it and trace the performance somehow. Maybe it's some specific api in which just doesent work well on Android. Google play can exclude certain devices, although you'd have to do some research as to which devices are powerful enough for your game. Check [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/158791/painfully-slow-on-android.html) also, it may help, if you didn't already.